# How to track mouse position every 3 seconds with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

I am working on a MEAN stack app and I need to track the mouse position every 3 seconds, save that data in an array and then store it into my database.

I started with this but I am no sure how to get it done:

HTML

```
<div class="field" ng-mousemove="captureCoordinate($event)">

My view is inside here

</div>
```

JavaScript

```
//I need to save this into my database
const data = {
      minutes,
      seconds,
      playerId,
      level,
      clicks,
      objectsToFind,
      tracking[]       <--- this should be the array with the tracking info
    }


//This is what I tried to get the mouse coordinates from my HTML
$scope.captureCoordinate = function($event){
      $scope.x = $event.x;
      $scope.y = $event.y;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the coordinates in a local variable on mouse move, then update the scope variable every 3 seconds with the value of this local variable.

Something like:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('myApp', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  const data = {
    tracking: []
  }
  let coords;
  $scope.trackCoords = function($event) {
    coords = [$event.pageX, $event.pageY];
  };
  setInterval(function() {
    data.tracking = coords;
    console.log(data.tracking);
  }, 3000);


}]);
```

```css
.field {
  margin: 2%;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="myApp" ng-app="myApp" class="field" ng-mousemove="trackCoords($event)">
  My view is inside here
</div>
```

Comment: The AngularJs space is so polluted with injecting $scope answers. It is 5 years since Google started recommending against injecting $scope and use controller as syntax or components.

Comment: @AdrianBrand I don't disagree, but the OP was clearly using `$scope` in his question, so I did the same in my answer. If the question was about migrating to `controllerAs` I would have answered differently.